# replace values between 2 files

Tags: replace, awk

I want to replace the third and fourth line of file_2 by the first two lines of a file_1

*Input:

file_1

```
what's your name?I am jo 
how are you?I am all right
```

file_2:

```
introduction

what's your name?
how are you?

this is jo's file
```

*Desired Output:

```
introduction 

what's your name?I am jo
how are you?I am all right

This is jo's file
```

tankx guys!

Comment: post the actual file contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can assume that file1 only contains two lines, this is simple:

```
sed -e '3rfile1' -e '3,4d' file2
```

If you cannot make that assumption, then use sed to prepare a new file that does satisfy that constraint:

```
sed -n 1,2p file1 > file1.tmp
```

If you want to overwrite file2 with the contents, you can use `sed -i`, but beware that will not work in all all versions of `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
NR==FNR { a[NR+2] = $0; next }
{ print (FNR in a ? a[FNR] : $0) }
' file1 file2
```

The only assumption the above makes is that the lines from file1 are offset by 2 from the target file.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 awk 'NR==FNR{if(FNR<3)a[NR]=$0;next}FNR==3||FNR==4{$0=a[FNR-2]}7' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'NR == FNR { a[i++] = $0; next; } FNR == 3 { $0 = a[0] } FNR == 4 { $0 = a[1] } 1' file1 file2
```

Another using `sed` and `cat`:

```
{ sed -n '1,2p; 4q'; cat file1.txt; cat; } < file2.txt
```

Comment: Since you do not use variable `i` on other places than in array to increment, you can use the `NR` like this `a[NR]=$0`

Comment: also, awk arrays start at 1, not zero.

Comment: @Jotne Yes that can be considered.

Comment: @EdMorton My code works with all awks that I have. Perhaps functions of awk prefer starting elements at 1 but I don't think awk does not allow 0 as an index. Consider `ARGV[0]` as well.

Comment: Yes, the code will function. Awk does allow arrays to start at zero but array[0] is usually used for "special" information e.g. ARGV[0] contains the name of the tool executing while ARGV[1] etc contains the actual values of the arguments. I sometimes use array[0] to hold the string passed to split(string,array), like $0 is the input record while $1, etc. are the fields. Starting user-defined arrays at zero will function fine, but it's likely to bite you later or make your code harder for others to read since the normal expectation is that they'll start at 1 just like all awk-generated arrays.

Comment: @EdMorton In C, `array[index++] = value` is natural or common so I don't think that's generally something that could be difficult to read even to others.

Comment: It's not difficult to read, just potentially difficult to remember several lines later when writing or reading `for (i=1;i<=max;i++) print array[i]` or similar that that won't work for `array` if it was user-defined rather than generated by split(), match(), asort(), asorti(), or patsplit() and is inconsistent with ARGV[] and $1..$NF. You've got no control over the awk builtin functionality generating arrays that start at 1 so why not always start user-defined arrays at 1 too for consistency? Oh well, just a suggestion, whatever works for you...

Comment: @EdMorton Nothing serious really. Sometimes it just depends on my mood what index number I'd start with. While sometimes you'd do `(i=1;i<=max;++i)`, sometimes it's length based: `(i=0;i<length;++i)`.